# Return transposed list of all strings in a row in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

In my Excel (for Mac 2011) sheet, the range B2:2 contains mostly empty cells, but some cells contain strings. I would like to print these strings into a transposed list beginning at A12. This list should exclude all empty cells and should print (in consecutive cells) all the strings in B2:2.

So far, I've tried `{=INDEX($B$2:$E$2, 0, SMALL(IF(NOT(ISEMPTY($B$2:$E$2)), COLUMN($B$2:$E$2)), ROW(1:1)}` as various websites and Stack Exchange answers have suggested, and `{=INDEX($B$2:$E$2, 0, SMALL(IF($B$2:$E$2<>"", COLUMN($B$2:$E$2)), ROW(1:1)`. However, these formulas have only simply transposed the entire range beginning at A12 when the B2 is filled. When B2 is not filled, no values appear.

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub FillRange()
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Dim counter As Long: counter = 0
Set rng = Range("B2:E2")

For Each cell In rng
    If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
       Range("A12").Offset(counter, 0) = cell
       counter = counter + 1
    End If
Next cell
End Sub
```

You can solve your problem easily using a macro.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Could you please [edit] your answer to give an explanation of why this code answers the question?